# Fourier transform of a nonlinear Schrödinger soliton

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, nonlinear-dynamics, soliton-theory

The nonlinear Schrödinger equation
$$
i\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}- |\psi|^2\psi
$$
has the single-soliton solution
$$
\psi(x,t)=A \frac{e^{iv(x-x_0)+i\frac{(A^2-v^2)}{2}t}}{\cosh(A(x-x_0 -vt))}.
$$

The simplest case of the soliton is with $x_0=0$ and at the initial time $t=0$, so
$$
\psi(x,0)=A \frac{e^{ivx}}{\cosh(Ax)}.
$$
Is there a closed-form expression for the spatial Fourier transform $\hat{\psi}(k,t)$ of this soliton solution ?

I have tried but I can't think of how to do the integral (and anyway Mathematica has been churning away at it for half an hour so if Mathematica can't do it then I certainly can't do it!), and google only comes up with results for "nonlinear Fourier transform" (aka scattering transform).

If there is no closed-form solution, then does anyone know any asymptotic expression for large $k$ ?

Comment: Changing variables $A(x-x_0-vt)=u$ means you need only the Fourier transform of $1/\cosh(u)$

Comment: Ah thanks, I've edited the question to do something similar, i.e. get the FT of the simplest soliton. It looks quite simple now and I'll have another attempt at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to evaluate

$$
I(k)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \frac{e^{ikx}}{2\cosh(x)}=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \ \frac{e^{ikx}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
$$

From which your Fourier transform follows with rescaling $Ax \to x$ and the replacement $k\to k+v/A$. We can use contour integrals to write $I$ as a sum which we can evaluate. The zeros of the denominator are at

$$
x_n=i\pi(n+1/2) \qquad, \qquad n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots
$$

The residue at each pole of the integrand is

$$
R_n=-(-1)^n\frac{i}{2}e^{-(n+1/2)\pi k}
$$

When $k>0$ we close the CCW integration contour in the upper half plane. The contribution due to the semicircular arc vanishes for large radius. The poles with $n\geq 0$ are enclosed. Then the residue theorem says

$$
I(k)=2\pi i\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty R_n=\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-(n+1/2)\pi k}
$$

On the right is a geometric sum which yields

$$
I(k)=\frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)
$$

When $k<0$ a similar analysis leads to the identical expression.

Comment: Thank you! I guess this method only works for the Fourier transform, and fails if I am using Fourier series (i.e. trying to find the coefficient $\hat{\psi}(k)$ of the Fourier expansion of the soliton, in a periodic domain), because of the inability to close the contour?

Comment: No problem! It will not carry over directly to the case of the Fourier series. You can still write the integral over a closed rectangular contour but the vertical sides parallel to the imaginary axis still contribute. Mathematica gives the Fourier cosine series in terms of hypergeometric functions